# What is an awkward constant and is there a relation to ad-hoc hypotheses?

Tags: soft-question, magnetic-fields, terminology

[I'm not entirely sure whether this is the right board, since it is not a technical but a soft question].

I'm reading the textbook "[Spin Dynamics - Basics of Nuclear Magnetic Resonance](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470511176.html)", 2nd ed., (2008), by Malcolm H. Levitt. On page 24, induced magnetism is introduced as follows:

> [...] The equilibrium value of the induced magnetic moment is often proportional to the applied magnetic ﬁeld **B**, and has the same direction. In SI units, this relationship is written as follows:
>   $$\mu_{induced}=\mu_0^{-1}V\chi \vec{B}$$
>   where $\mu_0 = 4\pi \cdot 10^{−7} \textrm{H}~\textrm{m}^{−1}$
>   is an **awkward constant**, called the *magnetic constant* or *vacuum permeability*.

Now, I wonder, what is an awkward constant? I assume it is not a technical term, but the author finds the introduction of this constant a far-fetched, counter-intuitive, or vague concept? I've heard people calling Einstein's cosmological constant $\Lambda$ ad-hoc. Is this related and if yes, how and if no, what makes the ad-hoc-ness different?

Comment: It's awkward because it's annoying to have to multiply by $\mu_0$ everytime. A system where $\mu_0 = 1$ would be nicer for this particular formula. There's nothing deeper here, I think.

Comment: And $\Lambda g^{\mu\nu}$ is "ad-hoc" in the sense that it's just a possible term, with no reason for its value, that can be added to Einstein's field equations that leaves them covariant.  Einstein was ambivalent about it, putting it in to prevent an expanding universe and then removing it when the Hubble red shift showed the universe to be expanding.  $\Lambda$ is back in now with the opposite sign to make the universe expand even faster than Hubble at large distances (eg Dark Energy).  No one seems to have a reason (that works) for why there is this value $\Lambda$ of constant curvature.

Comment: So what makes $\Lambda$ a "bad" (i.e. ad-hoc) constant while there are constants like Planck's $h$, that seem perfectly fine? Could it not be that $\Lambda$ has the same status as $h$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here "awkward" simply has its dictionary meaning. From [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20awkward),

> awk·ward (*adj.*)
>
> 1. causing difficulty; hard to do or deal with.
>
>    - deliberately unreasonable or uncooperative.
> 2. causing or feeling embarrassment or inconvenience.
> 3. not smooth or graceful; ungainly.
>
>    - uncomfortable or abnormal.

The writer evidently feels that the introduction of the constant makes the following development, on the whole, more ungainly and inconvenient. This is subjective: where some see an ungainly constant, others might see a useful handle for keeping dimensional analysis checks on the maths. That's all the story here, really.

This also has no relation to the description of the cosmological constant as '*ad hoc*', where the latter term also has its [dictionary meaning](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+ad+hoc). (Specifically, the cosmological constant feels like it's a bit of a hack contrived to make the field equations match the observed reality.)

Ever so rarely, on occasion, words in physics texts simply mean what they mean everywhere else.